# didInititate method for Spotify IOS SDK is not calling even though called sessionManager.initiateSession()

Tags: swift, spotify

I'm going through Spotify's authentication process and am requesting the scopes appRemoteControl for my app to control music and userReadCurrentlyPlaying for current song. I set up everything from the SPTConfiguration, SPTSessionManager, and SPTAppRemote, and their required delegate methods (SPTAppRemoteDelegate, SPTSessionManagerDelegate, SPTAppRemotePlayerStateDelegate) as well as initiating a session with the requested scopes whenever the user presses a button but I can't get the method

```
func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didInitiate session: SPTSession) {
    appRemote.connectionParameters.accessToken = session.accessToken
    appRemote.connect()
    print(session.accessToken)
}
```

to trigger. The authentication process fully works as it goes into my spotify app and returns back to my application and plays a song from the configuration.playURI = "" , however, the method above never is called. I followed the spotify demo project but still does not work. Here is my full code

```
class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

let spotifyClientID = Constants.clientID
let spotifyRedirectURL = Constants.redirectURI

let tokenSwap = "https://***********.glitch.me/api/token"
let refresh = "https://***********.glitch.me/api/refresh_token"

lazy var configuration: SPTConfiguration = {
    let configuration = SPTConfiguration(clientID: spotifyClientID, redirectURL: URL(string: "Lyrically://callback")!)
    return configuration
}()

lazy var sessionManager: SPTSessionManager = {
    let manager = SPTSessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: self)
    if let tokenSwapURL = URL(string: tokenSwap), let tokenRefreshURL = URL(string: refresh) {
        self.configuration.tokenSwapURL = tokenSwapURL
        self.configuration.tokenRefreshURL = tokenRefreshURL
        self.configuration.playURI = ""
    }
    return manager
}()

lazy var appRemote: SPTAppRemote = {
    let appRemote = SPTAppRemote(configuration: configuration, logLevel: .debug)
    appRemote.delegate = self
    return appRemote
}()

@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let requestedScopes: SPTScope = [.appRemoteControl, .userReadCurrentlyPlaying]
    sessionManager.initiateSession(with: requestedScopes, options: .default)
}
```

}

```
extension LogInViewController: SPTAppRemotePlayerStateDelegate {
func playerStateDidChange(_ playerState: SPTAppRemotePlayerState) {
    print("state changed")
}
```

}

```
extension LogInViewController: SPTAppRemoteDelegate {
func appRemoteDidEstablishConnection(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote) {
    print("connected")
    appRemote.playerAPI?.delegate = self
    appRemote.playerAPI?.subscribe(toPlayerState: { (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error subscribing to player state:" + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}

func appRemote(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote, didFailConnectionAttemptWithError error: Error?) {
    print("failed")
}

func appRemote(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote, didDisconnectWithError error: Error?) {
    print("disconnected")
}
```

}

```
extension LogInViewController: SPTSessionManagerDelegate {

func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didInitiate session: SPTSession) {
    appRemote.connectionParameters.accessToken = session.accessToken
    appRemote.connect()
    print(session.accessToken)
}

func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didFailWith error: Error) {
    print("failed",error)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Had to get a hold of the sessionManager from the LogInViewController by making an instance of it

```
lazy var logInVC = LogInViewController()
```

then added this line of code into the openURLContexts method in scene delegate

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    print("Opened url")
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
       return
    }
    logInVC.sessionManager.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: [:])
}
```

Comment: I am having this same issue. I have added the code that you posted above into a sceneDelegate class but the behavior is not changing. Wondering if you could help me out with this!

Comment: Sure! What I ended up doing was moving everything that handled the spotify log in process into the SceneDelegate. I saw one of the Spotify IOS demo projects that Spotify provided do this and I decided to proceed in that direction. Then in the sceneDelegate method openURLContexts, I added sessionManager.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: [:]) which allowed my app remote to connect

Comment: Got it. So the AppDelegate openURL method is in fact deprecated for the new Spotify SDK?

Comment: Yes. It is not used anymore and the sceneDelegate method openURLContexts is used instead.